# fabric js fontweight not working

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I am using this code to add `textbox` in `canvas` using `fabric js`,

```
var text = 'Type Text Here';
var textSample = new fabric.Textbox(text, {
    left: getCardLeft() + 100,
    top: getCardTop() + 10,
    width: 200,
    height: 20,
    fontFamily: 'Helvetica',
    fill: getColorPickerForegroundColor(),
    fontWeight: '',
    fontSize: parseInt('25'),
    originX: 'center',
    hasRotatingPoint: true,
    centerTransform: true,
});
canvas.add(textSample);
```

Which successfully add `textbox` into `canvas`.
Now, if i try to make it **`bold`** using this command

```
canvas.getActiveObject().set("fontWeight", "bold");
canvas.renderAll();
```

Working, But when try to change it to normal,

```
canvas.getActiveObject().set("fontWeight", "");
canvas.getActiveObject().set("fontWeight", "100");
canvas.getActiveObject().set("fontWeight", "normal");
canvas.renderAll();
```

not working.

I don't know where the issue is. Am i doing anything wrong here?.

Its behaving strange 
You can see it [here](http://screencast.com/t/HDVH6ckkr).

visit first [here](http://printhubpro.co.uk/printdog)
Then visit [here](http://printhubpro.co.uk/desiger)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just take `fabric.js` from [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.js) and replaced with mine, and working all.

Comment: after replacing my current fabric.min.js, still it is not working for me.

Answer (score 3):

The following code works for me. I see two points where I could failed at your side:

```
canvas.renderAll();
```

Needed to be rerendered properly. And also:

```
canvas.setActiveObject(textSample);
```

was neccessary for me. Because otherwise:

```
canvas.getActiveObject();
```

was undefined.
Now a full working code example:

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c', { selection: false });
var text = 'Type Text Here';

var textSample = new fabric.Textbox(text, {
  left: 300,
  top: 50,
  width: 200,
  height: 20,
  fontFamily: 'Helvetica',
  fill: "#fac",
  fontWeight: '100',
  fontSize: parseInt('25'),
  originX: 'center',
  hasRotatingPoint: true,
  centerTransform: true,
});

canvas.add(textSample);
canvas.setActiveObject(textSample);
canvas.getActiveObject().set("fontWeight", "bold");
canvas.renderAll();
canvas.getActiveObject().set("fontWeight", "100");
canvas.renderAll();
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: i already did render in my code. but its behaving strange. see http://screencast.com/t/HDVH6ckkr

Comment: i just edited my question little, please refer it again.may be you get anything wrong there which i couldn't able to find. thanks